# connection refused for vagrant ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, virtualbox, vagrant

I am having trouble connecting to my vagrant box using `vagrant ssh`. There are no error messages when running `vagrant up`, I can also connect directly using the VirtualBox ui.

When I run `vagrant ssh` I am just getting back the prompt without any message at all. If I add `VAGRANT_LOG=debug` I can see the command it's trying to run so if I copy that and run that manually:

```
ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2222 ...
```

I am seeing "Connection refused".

Any idea on how to continue debugging this ?

The host is Windows 7, the client is debian.

Comment: do you have `sshd` server installed on windows?`

Comment: @Jakuje Yes I had. But I found the real issue now - see the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the issue in my case. After I did a simple test "ssh localhost" on the windows host I noticed it actually connected to another machine than localhost.

That in turn made me remember that I had edited ~/.ssh/config some time ago, and checking that I noticed that I had forgotten to add a Host line which caused all ssh commands to go to the wrong server. Fixing that made vagrant work again.